# Can i remove bottom scroller on overflow:scroll?

Tags: scroll

So i have a popup window with a scroller. For scroller i used basic css element overflow: scroll. But the problem is scroller appears on the side and on the bottom. Now i want to know if there is anyway to remove the bottom scroller, because even though its locked its useless to me and it would look better without it. Ive googled it and havent found anything so if you have a solution please share it. If you need any of the code tell me and i will post it.

This is "my" css for popup (i got the code from http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin):

```
.reveal-modal-bg { 
    position: fixed; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    }

.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 520px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #eee url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    overflow:scroll;
    }

    .reveal-modal h1{
        color: green;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .reveal-modal strong{
        font-style: inherit;
    }

.reveal-modal.small         { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
.reveal-modal.medium        { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
.reveal-modal.large         { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
.reveal-modal.xlarge        { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}

.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

a better way of doing it would be

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
```

That way it means that if a page gets bigger with jquery and then you need to scroll the view won't get smaller and affect your measurements